# optionHTML and innerHTML overwriting `<option>` placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, jquery-select2

I am attempting to add a placeholder to my dynamic select fields. The issue is that my javascript that adds dynamic options based on the selection in the previous field is overwriting the first `<option>` tag used in order to set the placeholder. Every tutorial I have read (including select2 documentation and w3schools) adds the placeholder through a blank `<option>` tag.

I have tried adding a `placeholder=''` to the `<select>` tag but this simply doesn't do anything. I have also tried adding an `<option>` using javascript but this was overwritten as well.

#### Javascript

What it does: I have three fields being filtered. The first function filters the middle field based on the selection in the first. The second function filters the third field based on the selection in the second. This feature is working, but the issue is in the use of `optionHTML` and `innerHTML`.

```
// filter 'display' select2 fields
$(document).ready(function(){
    let college_select = document.getElementById('colleges');
    let building_select = document.getElementById('buildings');

    college_select.onchange = function() {
        $(building_select).empty();

        college = college_select.value;

        fetch('/building/' + college).then(function(response) {
            response.json().then(function(data) {
                let optionHTML = '';

                for (let building of data.buildings) {
                    optionHTML += '<option value="' + building.id + '">' + building.name + '</option>'
                }

                console.log(optionHTML);
                building_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;

                $(building_select).trigger('change');
            });
        });
    }
});

// filter 'display' select2 fields
$(document).ready(function(){
    let building_select = document.getElementById('buildings');
    let room_select = document.getElementById('rooms');

    building_select.onchange = function() {
        $(room_select).empty();

        building = building_select.value;

        fetch('/room/' + building).then(function(response) {
            response.json().then(function(data) {
                let optionHTML = '';

                for (let room of data.rooms) {
                    optionHTML += '<option value="' + room.id + '">' + room.room_number + '</option>'
                }

                console.log(optionHTML);
                room_select.innerHTML = optionHTML;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

#### HTML fields

*sorry about the formatting*

```
<select class="single-select" id="colleges" name="colleges">
              {% for college in colleges %}
                <option data-filterkey="{{ college.id }}" value="{{ college.id }}">{{ college.name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
          </select>
          <select class="single-select" id="buildings" name="buildings">
              {% for building in buildings %}
                <option data-filterkey="{{ building.college_id }}" value="{{ building.id }}">{{ building.name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
       </select>
       <select class="single-select" id="rooms" name="rooms">
          {% for room in rooms %}
         <option data-filterkey="{{ room.building.college_id }}" value="{{ room.id }}">{{ room.room_number }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

[image: Ideal output rendered]

Currently, the fields are automatically filled in because there is no placeholder so naturally there's a selection in each. Ideally, it should display the fields with the placeholders allowing the user to select one field at a time to get the desired result. (as seen above)

I'm simply out of ideas, so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your data some I just made up some. In the demo you can change the selection option while keeping the placeholder.

```js
var alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

var numeric = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#first-select').on('change', function(e) {

    var selectedType = $(e.target).val();
    $('#second-select .option-placeholder').html('select a ' + selectedType);

    var data = (selectedType === 'alphabet') ? alphabet : numeric;
    // remove option except the placeholder
    $('#second-select .option-value').remove();
    var secondselect = $('#second-select').first();
    // reset selection
    secondselect.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    // add option to the second list
    data.forEach(function(e) {
      secondselect.append($(
        '<option>', {
          'class': 'option-value',
          text: e,
          value: e
        }));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="first-select">
  <option disabled selected>select a type</option>
  <option value="alphabet">Alphabet</option>
  <option value="number">Number</option>
</select>

<select id="second-select">
  <option class="option-placeholder" disabled selected>select a ...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave this a try and it seems to work on the first load of the page, everything shows up fine. Although, when I select a value in the first field the rest automatically fill in. These are screenshots of my javascript (first) then my html (second): [js](https://ibb.co/P4XDmMV) [html](https://ibb.co/XzytQB6)

Comment: @Foltzy what do you mean by "the rest automatically fill in"?

Comment: This shows what I mean: [gif](https://makeagif.com/i/1wlUzn) I select the first field and the rest fill in.

Comment: This is what it should look like after the first selection: [screenshot](https://ibb.co/tQ4RTGt)

Comment: add class="option-value" to your <option> element

Comment: Which option element? I added it to my dynamically created `<option>`s but that didn't seem to work... @Mr. Brickowski

Comment: Add to those has attribute data-filterkey. You need to add the class to <option> so the script knows which to remove when the 1st selection is changed

Comment: I added that class to both the `data-filterkey` options in my html and the `<option>`s added through my js and neither worked. Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong spot. very close.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are looking through this with the same problem and similar code, I got my placeholders working. Using @Mr. Brickowski's answer and adding this,

```
optionHTML += '<option class="option-placeholder" disabled="" selected="">room..</option>';
```

before my dynamically created `<option>`s created the proper `<option>` needed for the placeholder.

View code snippet with highlighted change [here](https://ibb.co/7v8fRtz)